# How can i fix this error with my UpdateMotionhistory function in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I was learning about the updatemotionhistory function in opencv and thought of trying it. But for some reason i get this error" OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupport
ed array type) in cvGetMat, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc11-shared\openc
v\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 2482.

I noticed this error happens right after i implement my updatemotionhistory function which gives me this idea that i might have made a mistake in entering the parameters in the updatemotionhistory function.

This is my code:-

```
Mat frame,dst,tst;
double timestamp = (double)clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // I found this in the Opencv/samples  motempl.cpp
double duration = 1; //same as above , found this value in the opencv/samples/motempl.cpp

videocapture cap(0);
while(1)
    {
        cap.read(frame);
        cvtColor(frame,frame,CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cap.read(dst);
        cvtColor(dst,dst,CV_BGR2GRAY);
        absdiff(frame,dst,frame2);
        imshow("absolute frame difference",frame2);
        threshold(frame2,frame2,60,255,THRESH_BINARY);

        imshow("threshold",frame2);
        updateMotionHistory(frame2,tst,cap_timestamp,duration);

           waitkey(30);
```

}

I have two questions:- How exactly do i get the value of timestamp and duration values for the updatemotionhistory function? I have learnt that we can get the timestamp value as (int cap_timestamp = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) and how do i set the duration value?

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#updatemotionhistory):

```
void updateMotionHistory(InputArray silhouette, 
                         InputOutputArray mhi, 
                         double timestamp, 
                         double duration)
```

The `mhi` is a

> single-channel, 32-bit floating-point

Therefore, declare your `tst` with CV_32FC1, e.g. `Mat tst(frameHeight, frameWidth CV_32FC1);`,  can solve the OpenCV error.

The`timestamp` and `duration` define the "history" of your application. The `timestamp` means "now", which is a number grows over time; and `duration` means the "length of history you want to store in `mhi` (motion history image)", which is a constant.

Let's look at a simple one-dimension moving ball (B):

```
   B
---|---|---|---|---|--->
   0   1   2   3   4    x
```

Assume the ball is moving to right by one each time. At time 1, the ball is at:

```
       B
---|---|---|---|---|--->
   0   1   2   3   4    x
```

The silhouette (absdiff, same as in your code) at time(stamp) 1 is [True, True, False, False, False]. Assume the the initial value of `mhi` is [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] and `duration` is 2:

```
timestamp     silhouette             mhi
 1          [T, T, F, F, F]  -->  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
 2          [F, T, T, F, F]  -->  [1, 2, 2, 0, 0]
 3          [F, F, T, T, F]  -->  [1, 2, 3, 3, 0]
 4          [F, F, F, T, T]  -->  [0, 2, 3, 4, 4]
 ...
```

The `mhi` stores the history of timestamps. For example, `mhi[x] == t` means "the ball was moving at position x when the timestamp was t."

You can define your own `timestamp` and `duration`, according to your definition of "history" in the application. If you don't know how to determine the two parameters, here are two simple examples:

- `timestamp = clock(); duration = 5000 ms;` Use real time as timestamp, stores the history of the last 5 seconds.
- `timestamp = frameNumber(); duration = 50 frames;` Use video frame number as timestamp, stores the history of the last 50 frames. The `frameNumber()` simply returns `timestamp + 1.0` in your `while(1)` loop.

Comment: :- This is an amazing explanation. I wish i could vote for your explanation but since i am a new user, so my low reputation points doesnot allow me to vote for any posts. Sincerely, thanks from the bottom of my heart. Can you kindly suggest me any book which can help me in understanding this advanced concepts such as motion analysis in opencv and c++. It would be really helpful if i can get a book which can clearly explain this concepts because the opencv documentation doesnot elaborate the concept. Thanks again

Comment: I spent a lot of time reading papers and discussing with my advisor frequently when I was a student. Sometimes it's really hard to figure out the usage of OpenCV by reading only the documentation or searching the internet. Simply ask when you are in trouble. Many people can share experiences if you provide enough information.

Comment: :- Thank you for your reply. The problem is that i am a first year freshman and my lecturers simply laugh it out when i ask them for their assistance regarding computer vision and image processing. They say that i should wait until my senior year but i cant wait for so long. Also, i checked for books online and most of the books online use either Opencv With C or Python. I was looking for something that uses C++ but as you said reading papers and asking people will be the best option for me. Please advise me any if you feel that i need to do anything else.

Comment: Maybe you can read the [OpenCV turtorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html). The example code is simple. Run it, change some variables, check the result. And then search the internet or books about "why it works". Try to understand not only the function call in OpenCV, but also the algorithm behind the scene. It's not easy to learn by yourself, but it's fun :-)

Comment: :- Your advise is really helpful to me. I also would like to ask one last favor. I want to create a dynamic gesture based recognition system which can understand my hand gestures and perform certain operations. I have read online and found a couple of ideas such as HMM model, Neural Network, MHI, etc etc. I cant figure out which of them would be the best to implement. Can you kindly suggest me anything?

Comment: Learn the basics! Read all OpenCV tutorials before you start your the gesture recongition program. The tutorials are tools for you to solve the problem. After that, you'll have more ideas. A simple gesture recongnition program can work well even without HMM and neural network. The topics in the tutorials is enough to accomplish the task, try to think about it.